# Code after CFInclude seems to disappear or is not rendered

Tags: coldfusion

Having some issues with a ColdFusion application here. I'm trying to add in a  `<cfinclude template="header.cfm"/>` and it renders correctly however the rest of the cf code seems to disappear, not sure if its not being rendered or just not showing up because of the cfinclude statement running. This is for a page header I'm trying to insert.

Is there a way to insert the cfincludes and have it stop so the rest of the page can process? Does my question make sense?

```
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<!-- fwtable fwsrc="header.png" fwbase="default.gif" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "742308039" fwnested="1" -->
<tr>
 <td><img name="grantpro" src="images/grantpro.gif" width="411" height="80" border="0" alt=""></td>
 <td><img name="gpimage" src="images/gpimage.jpg" width="189" height="80" border="0" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center">
  <table width="599px" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><div align="center"><font size="5"><strong>FDC Menu</strong></font></div></td>
    </tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong>FDC Pending Proposals:</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2"><a href="fdclist.cfm?sort=name">By Applicant Name</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2"><a href="fdclist.cfm?sort=type">By Grant Type</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><strong>FDC Funded Proposals:</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2"><strong><em>Current Year</em></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><a href="fdcfundedlist.cfm?sort=name">By Applicant Name</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><a href="fdcfundedlist.cfm?sort=type">By Grant Type</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2"><em><strong>Prior Years</strong></em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><a href="fdcarchivelist.cfm?sort=name">By Applicant Name</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><a href="fdcarchivelist.cfm?sort=type">By Grant Type</a></td>
<cfinclude template="cssmenu/header.cfm"/>

  </table>
  <p align="center"><strong><a href="logout.cfm">Logout</a></strong></p> </td>
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code. I recommend putting together a [small self contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. The process might even help you find the issue. If not, it will give us something to work with.

Comment: Do you mean the code AFTER the cfinclude on the same page AS the cfinclude? In that case look for a cfabort inside the header.cfm. try catches also can be a problem.

Comment: This is probably invalid HTML inside. Look for something like a stray `<div>` or something. Consider saving the output and running it through https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code shows where the problem is

```
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><a href="fdcarchivelist.cfm?sort=type">By Grant Type</a></td>
  <cfinclude template="cssmenu/header.cfm"/>

</table>
```

**Solution 1:**

This is the recommended solution

The `<cfinclude>` probably should be moved outside of the `</table>`

**Solution 2:**

`cssmenu/header.cfm` would need to finish the current table row and start an new one. This is not recommended. It is not modular at all.

```
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="3">
    ... Content goes here ...
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `</tr>` before the `<cfinclude>`. Also it seems like an odd place to include a header, rather add another table row and td and include the header inside of the `<td>` not in between the table code as this is causing it to break.